# Windows 8 Automatically Create Date Folders within Applications

Tags: windows, date, directory

I have **Windows 8** and I was wondering if there was some way to create folders through applications using the current date.

For example some applications have a settings option that allows you to define the default save path when working on a project, for that specific application. Let’s say that within the application I have the default path to be **“C:\Program Files\Application\Saved Projects”**.

What I would like to do is have it automatically create a new folder under the **Saved Projects folder** with the **current date**. All projects will automatically get saved here. If I am working on more than one project that day it will just keep adding to that same folder. Once the next day comes it will then check to see if the current date folder is out there and if it isn’t it will **create a new one** for the day and save the projects there.

I tried something like this for a path **““C:\Program Files\Application\Saved Projects\%Date%”**, but that didn’t work, it just created a folder called **%Date%**. I thought within windows there was something I could put at the end of the path to automatically do this but I can’t seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I created a helper function to do a date for log files, but it will work for a folder:

```
private string FormatDateToString(DateTime date)
{
    return String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", date.Year, date.Month, date.Day);
}
```

Then, to create the folder path:

```
var path = Path.Combine(@"C:\Program Files\Application\Saved Projects", FormatDateToString(DateTime.Now));
```

Comment: Hi JRLambert, thanks for the post. How would I implement this? Maybe I posted my question in the wrong forum, not sure. Like one of the applications that I am working with is Camtasia Studio. Under the settings menu I specify the path on where to save the projects. The projects just get dumped in that folder, but I would like to somehow create a new sub-folder with the date and dump it in that folder. I don’t know how I could implement script for the application to read. If you know how, please explain. Thanks.

Comment: I should also note, that I know I can update the path each time I work with the program, it will create the folder for me. I would just like it to be automatic so I don't have to update the path each time I use it on a different day, or forget to update it.